# Ruby on Rails Advanced JSON Serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm looking to render an index of all articles along with a full article via JSON in my rails app, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to do it.

Here is my controller now:

```
if params[:id]
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
else
    @article = Article.published.not_draft.by_recent.first
end

respond_to do |format|

format.js { render :json => @article.to_json(
:except => [ :created_at, :updated_at, :draft, :id, :publish ], 
:include => {
    :comments => {
        :only => [:body]
    }
}),
:callback => params[:callback]}
end
```

What I'd like to do in the response is add an index of all articles, like so:

```
@index = Article.find(:all, :select => 'id, title')
```

The only way I've been able to do it, is put both the index and article into a hash or array and then put that to JSON.

```
@response = { :item => @article, :index => @index }
```

Full code with both:

```
@index = Article.find(:all, :select => 'id, title')

if params[:id]
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
else
    @article = Article.published.not_draft.by_recent.first
end

@response = { :item => @article, :index => @index }

respond_to do |format|

format.js { render :json => @response.to_json(), :callback => params[:callback]}

end
```

This would be fine, except now I cannot specify `:include` or `:except` and get it to render properly.

Answer (score 28):

You hint at the solution in your question.  You most likely want to build up a hash to render to JSON.  The preferred way of doing this now is by providing an implementation for the as_json method.  as_json provides a formal means of customizing to_json output by building up a hash containing the data you wish to encode.

A more thorough treatment of how as_json and to_json interact can be found on [Jonathan Julian's weblog](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/).

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear the code above works with the :include and :except.  And by works I mean it doesn't throw an error.  The problem is it includes comments for every article in the index.  I'm only looking to include comments for the :item and not any of the articles listed in the index.

I couldn't get nesting to work as a hash or an OpenStruct object.

Nesting on :include throws an error, nesting on :except doesn't throw an error, but nothing is filtered out, :created_at, etc. still show up.

```
...

@response = { :item => @article, :index => @index }

format.js { render :json => @response.to_json(
:except => {:item => [ :created_at, :updated_at, :draft, :id, :publish ]}, 
:include => { :item => {
        :comments => {
                :only => [:body]
        }
}}),
:callback => params[:callback]}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to nest the `:include`, `:except`, etc. like so:

```
:except => {:item => [ :created_at, :updated_at, :draft, :id, :publish ]}...
```

If that doesn't work, make it an object (e.g. an OpenStruct) instead of a hash.

-- Markus

Answer (score 1):

to_json has a :method option that includes the result of any method you name, you could define a method on that model that returns the additional data you want in your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

(Please accept an answer)

I think that the link that nirvdrum gave holds your answer. I only answer because nobody has mentioned `encode_json`.

In your case you should only be dealing with `as_json`. Either by building a hash (with various calls to `as_json`) and sending that to `render :json => ...` (without the call to `to_json`) or by simply implementing `as_json` on your model and letting rails do all the work. (But I suspect you'll need the former.)

If you really need some fancy js in your rendered response then you can implement `encode_json` in your classes (again, not `to_json`). For example:

```
class JsEmptyClosure
  def encode_json(*args)
    "jQuery[\"noop\"] || function(){}"
  end
  def as_json(*args) self end
end
```

This will now respond to `to_json` with valid js (but note it's not actually json).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, I am able to customize my json format for a model with several associations.

> render json: @posts.to_json(
>
> :except => [ :created_at, :updated_at, :user_id ],
>
> :include => {
>
> :user => {:only => [:email, :phone]},
>
> :location => {:only => [:title, :lat, :lon, :street, :city, :state,
>   :zipcode]},
>
> :uploads => {:only => [:image]}
>
> }
>   )

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend overloading the attributes method to return an alternat hash that will be automatically used in to_json output.

```
class Article
   def attributes
     { ... } # define your hash that you want to return at the '...'
   end
end
```

To me this seems much simpler than mucking around with to_json directly.