# Adding a parameter to an instance variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a instance variable that gets passed to my view. This variable 'post' has a user_id associated with it and I wanted to add an extra attribute called 'username' so I can also pass that and use it in the view.

Here is an example of what I would like to do.

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@post.username = User.find(@post.user_id).username
```

A username column does exist on my Users model but not my Songs model. So it won't let me use

```
@post.username
```

I know I can just make an entirely new instance variable and put that information in there but I would like to keep everything nice and neat, in one variable. Which will also make my json rendered code look cleaner.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the presence of a `user_id` in your `Post` model, you probably already have an association set up that can retrieve the username. It will probably save a lot of trouble to simply use the existing association:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
username = @post.user.username
```

If you're likely to be querying more than one post at a time (e.g., on an index page, calling `.includes` to tell Rails to eager-load an association will help you avoid [the N+1 problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations):

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user).all
```

Finally, to include the associated record in your JSON output, pass the `:include` parameter as you serialize:

```
# in controller
render :json => @post.to_json(:include => :user)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607873/ruby-on-rails-advanced-json-serialization) includes a much more comprehensive discussion of serialization options. Well worth a read.

Comment: thanks, I had no idea about this association. Is there anyway to add the username information to the json output for the page?

Comment: That's a separate issue, how are you rendering it to JSON? If you are using the defaults then pass options into the to_json call. E.g. render :json => @post.to_json(:include => :user). Or if you want the Post JSON object to have the username everywhere in your app then customize the `as_json` method in the Post model.

Comment: awesome thanks! that's exactly what I needed. I'm using the @post.user.username association in my views and added the json code to get the user in my controller. Thanks again for the quick replies.

Answer (score 2):

No need to pass a separate instance variable.
1. You can use `@post.user.username` in view itself.
2. Or you can create a helper and pass `@post.user`

```
def username user
 user.username
end
```

Comment: Ya @post.user.username worked just fine. However my json output still has user_id = #   is there anyway I can also add the username to the json output for the page?

Comment: You need to add user while rendering json as @post.to_json(:include => :user)

Comment: thanks asitmoharna this solution worked. thanks for the quick reply