# Get full image url from paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm trying to make an API for an app I'm making and I'm using paperclip gem to upload images to S3.

All has gone fine on the admin side of things but for the api I want to return results as efficiently as possible joining the paperclip image url to each Quiz.

I have an Icon model (this is obviously where paperclip is used) and a Quiz model. A Quiz belongs_to an Icon.

Here is my API method to return all published quizzes

```
def quizzes
    @quizzes = Quiz.published.joins('INNER JOIN icons ON icons.id = quizzes.icon_id').select('icons.image_file_name, quizzes.updated_at, quizzes.description, quizzes.id, quizzes.title')

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @quizzes }
        format.xml { render :xml => @quizzes }
    end
end
```

This only gives me the image name, not the full url to the image eg. only `love.png` instead of `http://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp-dev/icons/images/000/000/001/original/love.png?1342586714`

How do I get the full url? It's not stored in any of the fields of the Icon model that I can see?

--- EDIT ---

Here is what one of the returned records looks like in xml

```
<quiz>
  <description>Voluptatem inventore voluptatibus provident et officia. Consequatur voluptate alias. Laboriosam sit et. Non ea aut doloremque odit officiis. Unde mollitia asperiores omnis eaque at.</description>
  <id type="integer">5</id>
  <image-file-name type="NilClass">love.png</image-file-name>
  <title>Corrupti ea qui veniam et praesentium.</title>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2012-07-21T23:26:48Z</updated-at>
</quiz>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `@quizzes.first.icon.picture_from_url` ; the `picture_from_url` is a helper method provided by paperclip.

Comment: I can see that doing @quizzes.first.icon.image returns the correct and full url to the image, but how can I inject this into the results for every quiz returned?

Comment: I don't think you need to - the helper method just calculates it from the file name and the id of the model it's attached to.

Comment: I get that, but I'm trying render xml or json here which won't have access to the helper method. I need it included in the @quizzes array to be output in xml or json format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3485923/684934 looks related.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can explicitly call the conversions with additional model methods as arguments:

```
format.json { render @quizzes.to_json(:methods => :icon_url) }
format.xml { render @quizzes.to_xml(:methods => :icon_url) }
```

You would need that icon_url defined in your Quiz model to do it that way:

```
def icon_url
  icon.url
end
```

Comment: Doing that I do get an icon-url for each quiz object... but it outputs the whole icon object as yaml? And still no sight of the main url I'm after.

Comment: Check the edited answer -- I think that's the method for returning the url, you could also try `icon.picture_from_url`

Comment: Cleaner version of the last code block IMHO: `delegate :url, to: :icon, prefix: true`